# On a TCP connection, can the recipient control the TCP window size that the sender uses?

Tags: networking, tcp, tcp-window-scaling

The TCP window size is the amount of data that the sender will send before waiting for a TCP ack. Does the receiver have a way to control this (e.g., as part of the TCP handshake), or is it only the sender who can control?

Answer (score 5):

Yes the receiver can dynamically control the TCP window size, all along the TCP communication, not only at handshake, as stated in [RFC 793](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-1.5):

> Flow Control:
>
> TCP provides a means for the receiver to govern the amount of data
> sent by the sender.  This is achieved by **returning a "window" with
> every ACK** indicating a range of acceptable sequence numbers beyond the
> last segment successfully received.  **The window indicates an allowed
> number of octets that the sender may transmit** before receiving further
> permission.

Since you added [tcp-window-scaling](/questions/tagged/tcp-window-scaling), the TCP window scaling is just a multiplier used to overcome the initial limit of 64k for the maximum window size. This is negotiated using TCP options in the initial TCP handshake, as described in [RFC 7323](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7323#section-1.3):

> The Window Scale option negotiates fundamental parameters of the TCP
> session.  Therefore, it is only sent during the initial handshake.
> Furthermore, the Window Scale option will be sent in a `<SYN,ACK>`
> segment only if the corresponding option was received in the initial
> `<SYN>` segment.
>
> ....
>
> This option MAY be sent in an initial `<SYN>` segment (i.e., a segment
> with the SYN bit on and the ACK bit off).  If a Window Scale option
> was received in the initial `<SYN>` segment, then this option MAY be
> sent in the `<SYN,ACK>` segment.  A Window Scale option in a segment
> without a SYN bit MUST be ignored.

So this scaling factor can't be changed later. It's described further [there](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7323#section-2.1):

> The window scale extension expands the definition of the TCP window
> to 30 bits and then uses an implicit scale factor to carry this
> 30-bit value in the 16-bit window field of the TCP header (SEG.WND in
> [RFC0793]).  The exponent of the scale factor is carried in a TCP
> option, Window Scale.  This option is sent only in a  segment (a
> segment with the SYN bit on), hence the window scale is fixed in each
> direction when a connection is opened.

---

Here's an example of extreme and abnormal window control "abuse" from the receiver invented to delay scans used to propagate worms: Linux iptables' [`TARPIT`](https://manpages.debian.org/xtables-addons-common/xtables-addons.8#TARPIT) add-on target, based on LaBrea's *tar pit* (Jim McClurg, 2001 [PDF](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/tools/stop-port-scans-labrea-405)):

> `TARPIT`
> Captures and holds incoming TCP connections using no local
> per-connection resources.
> [...] play along like a listening server, but aside from sending an ACK or RST, no data is sent. [...]
> `--tarpit`
> This mode completes a connection with the attacker but **limits the
> window size to 0**, thus keeping the attacker waiting long periods of
> time. While he is maintaining state of the connection and trying to
> continue every 60-240 seconds, we keep none, so it is very
> lightweight. Attempts to close the connection are ignored, forcing the
> remote side to time out the connection in 12-24 minutes. This mode is
> the default.